# Prevent Vim from jumping to the beginning when invoking % range function

Tags: vim

I'm defining a Vim function:

```
function! HelloWorld() range
  echo "hello world"
endfunction
```

I open a text file with many lines with `vim -u NONE filename.txt`, jump to the last line with `G`, and call `HelloWorld()` with `:%call HelloWorld()`. I notice the cursor jumps to the first line. How to prevent this, i.e. keeping the cursor at current line? Thanks a lot!

P.S. The function mentioned above is just a minimal example. I know the problem disappears if I remove the `range` and call with `:call HelloWorld()`, but it's needed in my actual problem.

---

Edit:

```
function! HelloWorld() range
  let l:win_view = winsaveview()
  echo "hello world"
  call winrestview(l:win_view)
endfunction
```

won't work.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37839/how-to-restore-cursor-position-after-the-document-is-reformatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Matt. I eventually come up with the following solution. Keep function `HelloWorld` intact, then define a command that wraps around the function call. The idea is stolen from [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat/blob/00df1ac5df05247238cb2ae2a0770b62209e3aa7/plugin/autoformat.vim#L350).

```
command! -range -bar HelloWorld 
            \ let s:winview=winsaveview() |
            \ <line1>,<line2>call HelloWorld() |
            \ call winrestview(s:winview)
```

Now invoking `:%HelloWorld` will echo the text and won't move the cursor.

Comment: Why does invoking hello world cause it to jump cursor in the first place?

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37842.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this way:

```
function! HelloWorld() range

  " get current cursor position
  let l = line('.')
  let c = col('.')

  echo "hello world"

  " restore original cursor position
  call cursor(l,c)

endfunction
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, even after changing `l = line('.')` to `let l = line('.')` and same for the next line.

Comment: @Kevin ah then I'm not sure.. thanks for catching the omission of `let`. I'll leave the answer here in case it helps someone googling around for a similar problem for which this helps.